# Difference between each elements in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array with 4 int

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

and I want a difference between each element to another element, which the result looks like:

```
[a-b, a-c, a-d,b-c,b-d,c-d]
```

The sign does matter, I try shift the array, but there should be a better way to do this,
Cause this seems like some math problem that I forgot.

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])

array_2 = np.copy(array_1)
array_2 = np.roll(array_2,-1)
array_2[-1] = 0

array_3 = np.copy(array_2)
array_3 = np.roll(array_3,-1)
array_3[-1] = 0

result_1n2 = array_1-array_2
result_1n3 = array_1-array_3
result_last = array_1[0] - array_1[-1]

array_result = [result_1n2[0],result_1n3[0], result_last, result_1n2[1], result_1n3[1], result_1n2[2]]

print(array_result)

[-1, -2, -3, -1, -2, -1]
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: You might be better off using itertools.combinations.

Comment: I see, @Mad Physicist I will do that once I find the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**numpy**

At each element, you want to subtract off the elements that come after it.
You can get the indices for this using [`np.trui_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html). The rest is just subtraction:

```
a, b = np.triu_indices(4, 1)
result = array_1[a] - array_1[b]
```

The second argument to `triu_indices` moves you up one diagonal. The default is 0, which includes the indices of the main diagonal:

```
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
>>> b
array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64)

>>> array_1[a]
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3])
>>> array_1[b]
array([2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4])

>>> result
array([-1, -2, -3, -1, -2, -1])
```

If you ever need the input sorted by `b` instead of `a`, use [`np.tril_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html):

```
b, a = np.tril_indices(4, -1)
```

**itertools**

You can accomplish the same thing with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
result = [a - b for a, b in itertools.combinations(array_1, 2)]
```

Wrap the result in an array if you want.

Comment: Just try the itertools and that works perfect,thanks!

Comment: Also is there a way to give the result an identity? for instance, I can use loop to create a list of string [a-b, a-c, a-d,b-c,b-d,c-d] so result[0] is the difference between a&b. so when I process the result[x], I can go back the string[x] to know result[x] is the difference of which 2 element. Is there any module for this?

Comment: @WalkerCheung. Just look at the indices I used in my numpy solution. `array_1[a[x]]` is the first number and `array_1[b[x]]` the second.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the triu_indices approach seems to be much faster than itertools, thanks a lot for this answer

Comment: @SeanWilliam. Glad it helped. Generally, the only time python code will be faster than numpy is when you run out of memory

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different, but not as elegant as @Mad-Physicist 's answer. This uses broadcasting to get the differences.

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.arange(0,4,1);
bb = np.arange(4,8,1);
aa = aa[np.newaxis,:];
bb = bb[:,np.newaxis];
dd = aa - bb;
idx = np.triu_indices(4,1);
print(dd[idx])
```

Comment: Why bother computing all the possible combinations when you only need half of them?