# numpy to find products of all combinations of pairs of numbers in a matrix row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm given an n x m matrix and my goal is to find the "cross-product" of all the features, specifically each row in the product matrix is of the form
x<sub>ij</sub>jx<sub>ij'</sub>, j < j', j = 1, . . . , m, j' = (j + 1), . . . , m
so that the resulting row is a the product of all combinations of pairs in that row. Is there an elegant way to do this using numpy functions rather than python loops?

**Edit: example**

`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

should become

`[1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 2*3, 2*4, 3*4]`

which give:

`[2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]`

Comment: Have you tried implementing, maybe a for-loop version?

Comment: Can you please update the question with 1) A sample of your data, and 2) the expected output from the sample?

Comment: Added an example row input and output

Comment: Take a look at @Mad-Physicist 's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64071016/difference-between-each-elements-in-an-numpy-array/64074865#64074865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to generate all the possible subsets containing 2 elements of your original set.

**Short answer**:

```
# With m = 4                            
c = np.multiply(*np.add(np.triu_indices(4,1),1))
```

---

**General solution for any input array:**

If using `itertools` is an option then you can use:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

x = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2))
c = np.prod(x,-1)
```

`c` output:

```
array([ 2,  3,  4,  6,  8, 12])
```

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> `itertools.combinations(iterables,r)` : return r-length tuples in
> sorted order with no repeated elements.

And the number of elements in `c` correspond to the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) `C(n,k)`: `n` choose `k`, where `n = len([1,2,3,4])` and `k = 2`.

Noticed that `itertools.combinations()` only hide the for loops, but since there is no closed-form formula for this problem a for loop is inevitable.

**Numpy only solution**:

In your specific case, where your iterable are the suit of `n` positive integers `[1,2,3,4,...,n]` then you can noticed that the positive indice of an upper triangle 2D matrice of length `n-1` will produce the same result as `combinations` so:

```
# Number of elements in your array
n = 4
# Upper triangular matrice 
x = np.triu(np.ones([n-1,n-1]))
# Get the result
c = np.prod(np.argwhere(x)+np.arange(1,3),-1)
```

And again `c` output:

```
array([ 2,  3,  4,  6,  8, 12])
```

Or (with the help of @Nachikel, I wasn't aware of the existence of `np.triu_indices()`) the one liner:

```
c = np.multiply(*np.add(np.triu_indices(4,1),1))
```

---

**Benchmarking:**

[image]

and also with itertools:

[image]

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def itertools1(m):
    x = list(itertools.combinations(np.arange(1,m+1), 2))
    np.prod(x,-1)
    
    
def numpy1(m):
    n = m-1
    x = np.triu(np.ones([n,n]))
    np.prod(np.argwhere(x)+np.arange(1,3),-1)
    
def numpy2(m):
    np.multiply(*np.add(np.triu_indices(m,1),1))
    



   
def benchmark_time(m): 
    SETUP_CODE = ''' 
from __main__ import numpy1 
from __main__ import numpy2
from __main__ import itertools1
'''
    x = np.zeros([3,len(m)])
    for ind, m in enumerate(m):
        print('For m = {}'.format(m))
        TEST_CODE = ''' 
itertools1({})
        '''.format(m)
        # timeit.repeat statement 
        times = timeit.repeat(setup = SETUP_CODE, 
                              stmt = TEST_CODE, 
                              repeat = 10, 
                              number = 50) 
        x[0,ind] = np.average(times)
        print('Itertools1 give:\t{} s'.format(np.round(np.average(times),3)))
        
        TEST_CODE = ''' 
numpy1({})
        '''.format(m)
        
        times = timeit.repeat(setup = SETUP_CODE, 
                              stmt = TEST_CODE, 
                              repeat = 10, 
                              number = 50) 
        x[1,ind] = np.average(times)
        print('Numpy1 give:\t\t{} s'.format(np.round(np.average(times),3)))
        
        TEST_CODE = ''' 
numpy2({})
        '''.format(m)
        
        times = timeit.repeat(setup = SETUP_CODE, 
                              stmt = TEST_CODE, 
                              repeat = 10, 
                              number = 50) 
        x[2,ind] = np.average(times)
        print('Numpy2 give:\t\t{} s\n'.format(np.round(np.average(times),3)))
    return x

m = np.arange(10,150,10)
x = benchmark_time(m)

plt.plot(m,x.T)
plt.legend(('itertools', 'numpy triu', 'numpy triu_indices'))
plt.xlabel('m')
plt.ylabel('sec')
plt.show()
```